# vectorizing summation with double for loops in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have two for loops for very large arrays (10k x 10k) or more. Obviously this program's part is a huge bottleneck and very time-consuming task.

There are 4 arrays: `vm(10000,1)`, `va(10000,1)`, `yr(10000,10000)`, and `yi(10000,10000)`

```
for i = 1: 10000
    psum = 0;
    for j = 1: 10000
    psum = psum + vm(i)*vm(j)*(yr(i,j)*cos(va(i)-va(j)) + yi(i,j)*sin(va(i)-va(j)));
    end
pcal(i) = psum;
end
```

Comment: Try to get some inspirations about vectorization [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) and element-wise multiplication [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) and try to produce a own first solution to your question and you'll be help from there. You can measure time in matlab with the [tic-toc](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html) pattern

Comment: I would also recommend not using directly the value 10000 but instead using `size` or `numel`. If tomorrow your input vectors have 5000 elements you will get an error but if the vectors have 20000 elements you will hardly notice that half of them are not computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it's straightforward to calculate the sum in one go. Basically, you create arrays where the elements are the appropriate products and differences of `vm` and `va`, respectively (using `bsxfun`), followed by element-wise multiplication and summation across the rows.

```
pcal = sum(bsxfun(@times,vm,vm') .* (...
    yr.*cos(bsxfun(@minus,va,va')) + ...
    yi.*sin(bsxfun(@minus,va,va'))),2);
```

Note that in vecorization, you tend to trade memory vs CPU cycles. If you do not have enough RAM, you may end up paging, which would slow the vectorized solution to a crawl.

Comment: Thanks very much Jonas, this code works very well. This is the answer to my problem

Answer (score 0):

The fastest option will be @Joans answer. However, in case you run into memory problems, here is a semi-vectorized option (only one loop):

```
pcal = zeros(N,1); % N is the 10000 in your example
for m = 1: N
    va_va = va(m)-va(1:N);
    pcal(m) = sum(vm(m)*vm(1:N).*(yr(m,1:N).'.*cos(va_va)+yi(m,1:N).'.*sin(va_va)));
end
```

And here is a benchmarking of this method along with yours and @Joans one, and another method using `ndgrid`:

```
function sum_time
N = 10000;
vm = rand(N,1);
va = rand(N,1);
yr = rand(N);
yi = rand(N);

loop_time = timeit(@() loop(N,vm,va,yr,yi))
loop2_time = timeit(@() loop2(N,vm,va,yr,yi))
bsx_time = timeit(@() bsx(vm,va,yr,yi))
ndg_time = timeit(@() ndg(N,vm,va,yr,yi))
end

function pcal = loop(N,vm,va,yr,yi)
pcal = zeros(N,1);
for m = 1: N
    psum = 0;
    for n = 1: N
        psum = psum + vm(m)*vm(n)*(yr(m,n)*cos(va(m)-va(n)) +...
            yi(m,n)*sin(va(m)-va(n)));
    end
    pcal(m) = psum;
end
end

function pcal = loop2(N,vm,va,yr,yi)
pcal = zeros(N,1);
for m = 1: N
    va_va = va(m)-va(1:N); % to avoid calculating twice
    pcal(m) = sum(vm(m)*vm(1:N).*(yr(m,1:N).'.*cos(va_va)+yi(m,1:N).'.*sin(va_va)));
end
end

function pcal = bsx(vm,va,yr,yi)
pcal = sum(bsxfun(@times,vm,vm') .* (...
    yr.*cos(bsxfun(@minus,va,va')) + ...
    yi.*sin(bsxfun(@minus,va,va'))),2);
end

function pcal = ndg(N,vm,va,yr,yi)
[n,m] = ndgrid((1:N).',1:N);
yr_t = yr.';
yi_t = yi.';
va_va = va(m(:))-va(n(:));
vmt = vm(m(:)).*vm(n(:));
psum = vmt.*(yr_t(1:N^2).'.*cos(va_va)+yi_t(1:N^2).'.*sin(va_va));
pcal = sum(reshape(psum,N,N)).';
end
```

and the results (for `N = 10000`):

```
loop_time =
       7.0296
loop2_time =
       3.3722
bsx_time =
       1.2716
ndg_time =
       6.3568
```

so taking one loop out saving ~50% of the time.

Comment: Thanks EBH, I appreciate your explanation with detailed options

Answer (score 0):

you can reformulate your equation according to theses [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities):

```
sin(a-b) = sin a cos b - cos a sin b;
cos(a-b) = cos a cos b + sin a sin b;
```

so precompute sine and cosine and use them in loop or bsxfun. this is loop version:

```
yr = rand(10000);
yi = rand(10000);
va = rand(1,10000);
vm = rand(1,10000);
sin_va = sin(va);
cos_va = cos(va);
for i = 1: 10000
    pcal(i) =  sum(vm(i)*vm.*(yr(i,:).*(cos_va(i) * cos_va + sin_va(i) * sin_va) + yi(i,:).*(sin_va(i) * cos_va - cos_va(i) * sin_va)));
end
```